# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el nombre del archivo de la selección 2 aparezca en su label , sin afectar la primera selección?

Tags: javascript, html

> Quiero que al hacer click en el botón selección 2  no aparezca el mismo nombre del documento en los dos label, deseo que cada uno de los input file coloque en el label el archivo seleccionado según corresponda.

```js
const selectFile = function() {
  let regex = /[^\\]+$/
  this.choose,
    this.selected
  this.msg = str => {
    let prefix = '[selectFile.js]\n\nError: '
    return alert(prefix + str)
  }
  this.check = () => {
    if (this.choose && this.selected != null) {
      let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose),
        selected = document.getElementById(this.selected)
      choose.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        if (choose.value != '') {
          selected.innerHTML = choose.value.match(regex)
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.msg('Targets not set.')
    }
  }
  selectFile.prototype.targets = (trigger, filetext) => {
    this.choose = trigger
    this.selected = filetext
  }
  selectFile.prototype.simulate = (e) => {
    if (this.choose != null) {
      let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose)
      if (typeof choose != 'undefined') {
        choose.click()
        this.check()
      } else {
        this.msg('Could not find element ' + this.choose)
      }
    } else {
      this.msg('Targets not set.')
    }
  }
};

let seleccion = new selectFile();
seleccion.targets('choose', 'selected');
document.querySelector('#seleccion').addEventListener('click', seleccion.simulate);

let seleccion2 = new selectFile();
seleccion2.targets('choose', 'selected2');
document.querySelector('#seleccion2').addEventListener('click', seleccion2.simulate);
```

```html
<div id="fondo">
  <input type="file" hidden id="choose">
  <button id="seleccion" type="button">seleccion</button>
  <label id="selected" for="seleccion">Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>

<div id="fondo">
  <input type="file" hidden id="choose">
  <button id="seleccion2" type="button">seleccion2</button>
  <label id="selected2" for="seleccion2">Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando mismo ID para los dos campos tipo `file`; los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id).

Para el segundo campo, usa otro ID:

```
<input type="file" hidden id="choose2">
```

Y en Javascript lo activas:

```
seleccion2.targets('choose2', 'selected2');
```

```js
const selectFile = function() {
  let regex = /[^\\]+$/
  this.choose,
    this.selected
  this.msg = str => {
    let prefix = '[selectFile.js]\n\nError: '
    return alert(prefix + str)
  }
  this.check = () => {
    if (this.choose && this.selected != null) {
      let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose),
        selected = document.getElementById(this.selected)
      choose.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        if (choose.value != '') {
          selected.innerHTML = choose.value.match(regex)
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.msg('Targets not set.')
    }
  }
  selectFile.prototype.targets = (trigger, filetext) => {
    this.choose = trigger
    this.selected = filetext
  }
  selectFile.prototype.simulate = (e) => {
    if (this.choose != null) {
      let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose)
      if (typeof choose != 'undefined') {
        choose.click()
        this.check()
      } else {
        this.msg('Could not find element ' + this.choose)
      }
    } else {
      this.msg('Targets not set.')
    }
  }
};

let seleccion = new selectFile();
seleccion.targets('choose', 'selected');
document.querySelector('#seleccion').addEventListener('click', seleccion.simulate);

let seleccion2 = new selectFile();
seleccion2.targets('choose2', 'selected2');
document.querySelector('#seleccion2').addEventListener('click', seleccion2.simulate);
```

```html
<div id="fondo">
  <input type="file" hidden id="choose">
  <button id="seleccion" type="button">seleccion</button>
  <label id="selected" for="seleccion">Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>

<div id="fondo">
  <input type="file" hidden id="choose2">
  <button id="seleccion2" type="button">seleccion2</button>
  <label id="selected2" for="seleccion2">Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo realicé así  me di cuenta del error.